# Unicode arrows for Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, unicode, input

I want to type `↑` using the keyboard. Both the `Character Map` app and this website http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2191/index.htm says to use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>2191</kbd>. But when I type that I get back `Å`. For down arrow `2193` I get back `æ`.

No matter what program I use, I get the same results. Chrome, Firefox, Visio, Excel, etc.

Comment: You can end application (like VMWare/VirtualBox/Evernote) one by one to check if its setting conflict with Windows. Ref: http://blog.oliver-mueller.com/-102

Answer (score 3):

By default in Windows you can't type hexadecimal Unicode codepoints. All values input with <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>numkey</kbd> is treated as **decimal** value modulo 256, which means you can't enter a character higher than 255 either.

To use hexadecimal Alt code input you must create a registry key named `EnableHexNumpad` with type `REG_SZ` in `HKCU\Control Panel\Input Method\`, set its value to 1 then reboot. After that you can type the character as <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>+</kbd> then <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Unicode value</kbd>.

- For example typing <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>+</kbd><kbd>2</kbd><kbd>1</kbd><kbd>9</kbd><kbd>1</kbd> will result in the arrow character you want.

In MS Word you just need type the Unicode value and then press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>, or `U+<Unicode codepoint>` then <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>

- For example typing 2191 or U+2191 then <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> will enter ↑ to your document.

More on this:

- [Alt code wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alt_code#History_and_description)
- [Insert ASCII or Unicode Latin-based symbols and characters](https://office.microsoft.com/en-in/word-help/insert-ascii-or-unicode-latin-based-symbols-and-characters-HA010167539.aspx)
- [How to enter Unicode characters in Microsoft Windows](http://www.fileformat.info/tip/microsoft/enter_unicode.htm)

Answer (score -1):

Copy the graphic for the 'up arrow', (for example, here from this post: `↑`) and paste it into a document.

By changing font sizes it resizes perfectly. A little klugey but simpler than the other [answer](https://superuser.com/a/830527/213131).